# Swimlane ngx-pie-chart pie-label-line not showing issue

Tags: angular, bar-chart, pie-chart, micro-frontend, ngx-charts

[image]

When smaller values came in pie chart, label lines are not displayed.
ngx-pie-chart example: The length is 4 comparing the values like(640,100,27,8,4) only the 3 values show in the
pie line label the last two values pie label line not display.

swimlane/ngx-charts version
20.1.0

If anyone knows about this issue kindly help me.

I am expecting the pie label line comes for all the values including smaller values also.

Comment: Even I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I think labelVisibility is going to be helpful but dont know how to use it. We need an answer for that

Comment: There is already a bug reported in GitHub : https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1284
Unfortunately, there is no solution yet...